# How to specify to use Convert.DBNull automatically as sql parameter value when the original parameter is null in c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, ado.net, sqlcommand

I need to use Convert.DBNull for every single null value while adding parameters of sqlCommands. It's tedious because I have a lot of sql commands. So it would be lot easier if there is any way like setting this Object(Convert.DBNull)as parameter whenever it gets a null value as parameter.

Example:
I have a code like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterLastModifiedBy", Master.LastModifiedBy);
```

As variables like Master.LastModifiedBy might be null sometimes, therefore I have to reformat that into this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterLastModifiedBy", Master.LastModifiedBy?? Convert.DBNull);
```

I don't want to do this reformatting in all parameters. So, what else can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Write your own extension method `AddWithValueWithNiceNullHandling` (or whatever name you want) which does the `??` for you. This will thus allow you to still pass `null` when you explicit want to, but call your new method to use `DBNull.Value` instead.

Comment: Please provide the body of the method as answer so that I can mark that as correct one

Comment: Honestly @ste-fu's answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) Library of some sort. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) would be good places to start.

Or you can write your own method to add a null check to each parameter.

Finally (specifically) thinking about last modified date, you could *always* set it, which would probably simplify a bunch of queries

EDIT:

Your extension method could look like this:

```
public static class SqlExtensions // needs to be in a static class
{
    public static void AddWithValueAndNullCheck(this SqlParameterCollection collection, string parameterName, object value)
    {
        if (object == null)
        {
            collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use any ORM. Would you please provide the body of that extension method?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use an ORM @Exceptionhandler?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the method